# onmouseover on <li> in reactjs not being actioned

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a project in ReactJS and I am trying to do a `onMouseOver` event on a `<li>` in a functional component but for some reason the onMoueOver isn't being triggered. Below is the code:

```
function KBSidebar(props)
{
    const itemOnHover = (itemIndex) => {
        alert(itemIndex);
    }

    const items = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < props.headings.length; i++)
    {
        if (i !== props.selected_heading.heading_index)
        {
            items.push(
                <li data-index={i} onMouseOver={() => itemOnHover(i)} key={props.headings[i].KBDocHeadingID} onClick={() => props.heading_selectedFunc(i, props.headings[i].KBDocHeadingID)} className='kb_item'>{props.headings[i].Heading}</li>
            )
        }
        else
        {
            items.push(
                <li data-index={i} onMouseOver={() => itemOnHover(i)} key={props.headings[i].KBDocHeadingID} className='kb_item active'>{props.headings[i].Heading}
                    <span style={{color: 'red', fontWeight: 'bold', display: 'none'}}><FaTrash /></span>
                </li>
            )
        }
    }

return (
        <div className='kb_documentation_sidebar'>
            <button onClick={props.addHeadingFunc} className='btn btn-link'><FaPlusCircle /> Add New Heading</button>

            <ul className='kb_items'>
                {items}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
```

I've tested this in a normal HTML/JS page and it works fine so why doesn't this work in ReactJS?

Comment: It's working for me! Can you add your code to sandbox ?

Comment: Hi Boardy, your code works just fine. Here's the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9uufkx

Comment: @DharaVihol I tried creating a sandbox and it works there, so not sure why it doesn't work in my own project that's weird.

Comment: @IgorGreg Not sue where state and hooks come into it, I want to perform an action on hover event, I don't want to change any state of the component

Comment: It looks like my dev tool was blocking was alert on mouseenter. Did a console.log and its working